# Scrapy: Creating a new item for each argument

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy newbie here. I'm currently trying to extend my crawlspider so it can take in multiple arguments from a text document (instead of manually typing in each arguments into the command line like `scrapy crawl crawl5 -a start_url="argument"`). Currently, I can input one argument and that generates a few items. But I'd like some guidance on two problems:

1. How can I create an item for each argument?
2. How can I use that item as a container for the items I generate from each argument?

My goal here is to sort of imitate running my crawlspider multiple times, while keeping the items returned from each argument separate.

EDIT.. here's my code- as you can see it's a scraper for thesaurus.com

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from thesaurus.items import ThesaurusItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'crawl5'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/%s" %kwargs.get('start_url')] 
        self.allowed_domains = ["thesaurus.com"]
        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//div[id='paginator']//a/@href"))),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/%s/.$' %kwargs.get('start_url'), 'http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/%s/..$' %kwargs.get('start_url'))), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
        )
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'syn_of_syns')]"):
            print(sel)
            item = ThesaurusItem()
            item['mainsynonym'] = sel.xpath("div/div/div/a/text()").extract()
            item['definition'] = sel.xpath("div/div/div[@class='def']/text()").extract()
            item['secondarysynonym'] = sel.xpath('div/div/ul/li/a/text()').extract()
            yield item

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'syn_of_syns')]"):
            print(sel)
            item = ThesaurusItem()
            item['mainsynonym'] = sel.xpath("div/div/div/a/text()").extract()
            item['definition'] = sel.xpath("div/div/div[@class='def']/text()").extract()
            item['secondarysynonym'] = sel.xpath('div/div/ul/li/a/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: I suggest you add the code that you use to generate one item, so you can be guided further. To add more item to start_urls is easy, you just add them in an array, probably you have something more complex in mind, so post it here.

Comment: Actually, I think it makes more sense to create an item for each argument taken in.. let me edit the question

Comment: I will probably not help you, because I do not use the link extractor - I just use base spider, in my opinion it is more straightforward to use. Looks like you your code is duplicated between these 2 methods. I saw the Thesaurus.com and it looks like they have no catalogue so you need to use the search to look for links. Selenium in combination with Scrapy might be good for this purpose to stimulate what user would do on a page: enter text and click search. Perhaps you would need to feed a predefined list of words in an array to look for.